# Using custom attrs in styles.xml in android

Tags: android, xml

I made a custom attribute style as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="EffectsTextView">        
        <attr name="strokeWidth" format="float" />
        <attr name="strokeMiter" format="float" />
        <attr name="strokeColor" format="color" />        
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

In Layout file, I could use this custom attribute assigning a namespace for this attribute:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
xmlns:effects="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto/com.base.view.EffectsTextView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#40000000" >

 <com.base.view.EffectsTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="290dip"
        android:layout_height="80dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="SETTINGS"
        android:textSize="44dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"  
        effects:strokeWidth="10"  />    <--- custom tag "effects"
```

However it was not recognizing this custom tag in styles.xml

```
<style name="EffectsHeaderTextStyle">
     <item name="effects:strokeWidth">10</item>
</style>
```

Error: No resource found that matches the given name, effects, though I put the namespace same as I did in RelativeLayout file.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Change your XML to:

```
xmlns:effects="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.base.view.EffectsTextView"
```

And change your style:

```
<style name="EffectsHeaderTextStyle">
    <item name="strokeWidth">10</item>
</style>
```

I did something similar with fonts:

https://github.com/androidfu/CodeExamples/tree/master/com.androidfu.CustomFontsDemo

Comment: This totally works, but I found that in IntelliJ I would get a 'declared namespace is never used' warning. I removed the xmlns declaration and it still worked. It seems, at least in IntelliJ, that you don't need namespaces for attributes of custom views...

Answer (score 0):

Gradle doesn't recommend using the actual package in `xmln:`.
In Gradle projects, the actual package used in the final APK can vary; for example, you can add a .debug package suffix in one version and not the other. Therefore, you should not hardcode the application package in the resource; instead, use the special namespace `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` which will cause the tools to figure out the right namespace for the resource regardless of the actual package used during the build.