# It is possible to create a button by passing parameters in the XML android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to create a button by passing parameters in XML ?
doing it that way ?

```
<Button
    button:typeParameter="primary"
    button:size="md"/>
```

And after passing these 2 parameters the button is created as it should be, is it possible to do this?

I already have a button on which I created new attributes, now I want to know if it is possible to pass parameters and this button be called, without the need for the developer to have to code all these lines.

```
<customButton
    android:fontFamily="@font/mondrian_family_font"
    app:fontFamily="@font/mondrian_family_font"
    android:id="@+id/mdnButtonPrimary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:text="Button primary"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:textColor="@color/color_neutral_lightest"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_XXS"
    mdnbutton:radius="@dimen/border_radius_pill"
    mdnbutton:defaultColor="@color/color_brand_primary_medium"
    mdnbutton:focusColor="@color/color_brand_primary_darkest"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
```

It is possible that he will use these attributes after he installs my library.
Now I want that when the developer is going to create his layout, instead of creating a button from scratch, he just passes parameters in the XML and the button is rendered.

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for [custom `View` attributes](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#customattr). However, you'd have to create a custom `Button` subclass, and you wouldn't be able to specify only those two custom attributes, there. You'll need at least the standard `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes set, as well.

Comment: I strongly recommend you read this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button

Comment: Yes, I know I will need to create custom attributes, I just need to know if it is possible to pass two parameters in the XML and after I pass these two parameters the button is created as it should be.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What exactly do you mean by "the button is created as it should be"? What are you thinking might be incorrect or improper?

Comment: I pass these two parameters and the button is created with background, with rounding and other things.
I already do the button configuration, I just want to simplify things.

Comment: Still not clear. `Button` gets its standard look from pre-defined framework attributes and values. If you want to create custom attributes for your own use, those aren't going to interfere with those framework attributes, but you have to handle reading and applying those attributes yourself in the subclass.

Comment: please see my updated question.

Comment: A lot of that stuff is usually handled with styles. If you really want to do it with custom attributes instead, then yeah, you can, but as I mentioned, you have to handle that yourself in your custom subclass.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this? I have a java class that controls the behavior of all these attributes that I created, I just really need to know where to start to remove the need for the developer to have to create this button all from scratch, passing just one type and one size.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this? I have a java class that controls the behavior of all these attributes that I created, I just really need to know where to start to remove the need for the developer to have to create this `Button` all from scratch, passing just one `type` and one `size`.

Comment: i think what your looking for is to put this as a style

Comment: how would it work to put this as a style? @IvoBeckers

Comment: i will write an answer. just a sec

Comment: thank u so much @IvoBeckers

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for you to make it as a style. But having it depend on two attributes is a bit hard, so I suggest to make a style for every combination of the two, so you have a style called `primaryMd` for example.
Your button would be like this:

```
<Button
    style="@style/primaryMd" />
```

you can define this style in you res folder in styles.xml like this for example then:

```
<resources>

    <style name="primaryMd" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/mondrian_family_font</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:text">Button primary</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_neutral_lightest</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_size_XXS</item>
        <item name="mdnbutton:radius">@dimen/border_radius_pill</item>
        <item name="mdnbutton:defaultColor">@color/color_brand_primary_medium</item>
        <item name="mdnbutton:focusColor">@color/color_brand_primary_darkest</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I'm not entirely sure if it works with these custom `mdnbutton` attributes, but you could try it out maybe

Comment: how to use my `radius` and `defaultColor` attribute?

Comment: judging from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824289/using-custom-attrs-in-styles-xml-in-android/15824342 you might be able to declare them in the style without the `mdnbutton:` in front of it

Comment: there is a possibility that I don't need to repeat the attributes, as I have several types of `Buttons`, and sometimes they only change one `Color`.

Comment: It works, it's a good solution. However, as I have several types of `buttons` that sometimes what change from one to the other is a `border`, or a `background`. The problem is that I have to keep repeating the attributes several times. @IvoBeckers

Comment: one style can inherit from another style by using the `parent=` after the name of the style. That can reduce having to repeat a lot of things. Also when you apply a style to a button you can still overwrite any values at the button itself, for example applying this primaryMd style to a button but also typing `android:paddingLeft="60dp"` would give it 60dp instead of the 40dp of the style